# HTML :How to check whether the file is exist in local PC or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, file

I am developing a Django web application in which I want to check if an application is installed or not on the client PC (the user's local machine).

A solution I came up with would be to check if a folder exists or not, for example the path `C:\Program Files\TheApplication`. Is it possible to check this from a Django application using any combination of Javascript, HTML and Django/Python?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript cannot access the local file system.  Evidently HTML5 provides a way for local storage but not full blown access.

Comment: Is there any other way to access?

Comment: other than launching a program that is installed on your computer or using an ActiveX control.   There is no trivial way.

Comment: @TMcKeown This answer might be corrent 2-3 years ago. But now its not correct. Check this [Link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Ok, HTML5 may be a way.

Comment: @Prateek the File API doesn't grant the browser access to the file system, only lets you manipulate user-supplied files in a sandboxed environment. So in the scope of this question the answer is still: no, you can't read the contents of "c:\program files" directory.

Comment: BTW JavaScript is a programming language and as such has the ability to manipulate files and directories for example in phonegap, node.js or browser extensions/plugins. It's a limitation of a particular environment (client-side scripts in a web browser) that doesn't expose such APIs for security reasons, not the language itself.

Comment: @pawel You mean we can read file from `C:\Program Files\1.txt`. Is it

Comment: @pawel Try this [Read File Demo](http://cl.ly/3h2R222J1j47).

Comment: @Prateek it still "only lets you manipulate user-supplied files", like I've stated before. The user has to choose the file to be manipulated, it's just obvious that a random script from the internet can not sniff around users file system, such a security hole would be every hacker's wet dream and it's basically what OP asks for. Trusted code, on the other hand, has this ability: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O but it will only work after the user has willfully installed an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that using a signed Java Applet could achieve such functionality. As far as I remember if applet is signed, you have full access to the users OS.